# StackPanel visibility VS Grid Visibility

Tags: wpf, mvvm, visibility

I am using MVVM application and there is something that don't understand..
What is the difference between StackPanel visibility and Grid Visibility.
if I have this Grid...

```
 <UserControl x:Class="Envitech.Setup.Presentation.Views.MonitorScreenViews.MonitorAlertViews.MonitorAlertView" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="438" d:DesignWidth="842" xmlns:popup="clr-namespace:Envitech.Setup.Presentation.Views.GlobalViews">
    <DockPanel DataContext="{Binding MonitorAlertViewModel}" Width="824" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="435">                        
        <Grid DataContext="{Binding CurrentMonitorAlert}" Height="422" Visibility="{Binding Path=NoMonitorsMessageVisibility, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
            <Label Content="Value" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,103,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />            
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

visibility does not work, but if i do it this way...

```
 <UserControl x:Class="Envitech.Setup.Presentation.Views.MonitorScreenViews.MonitorAlertViews.MonitorAlertView" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="438" d:DesignWidth="842" xmlns:popup="clr-namespace:Envitech.Setup.Presentation.Views.GlobalViews">
    <DockPanel DataContext="{Binding MonitorAlertViewModel}" Width="824" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="435">                
        <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding Path=NoMonitorsMessageVisibility, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
        <Grid DataContext="{Binding CurrentMonitorAlert}" Height="422">
            <Label Content="Value" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,103,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />            
        </Grid>
        </StackPanel>       
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

visibility works just fine.

Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: The binding does not exist.

Comment: what? You mean the path does not exist? It's impossible to help you if you don't provide sufficient information. Something we can copy/paste to repro would be ideal.

Comment: In other words, why the binding doesn't work for the grid? why do i need to wrap it with a stackpanel with the same binding and it works.

Comment: Again, because you've not provided a repro, I can't tell you why. I suspect there's more to it than is evident from your question. Please provide a copy/paste repro so we can actually help you.

Comment: O.K. I edited my question and copied pasted the code. I want the grid visibility will be affected from NoMonitorsMessageVisibility, and it's not working (see first code part), unless I wrap it with a stackPanel and use the visibility on it (see second code part). thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataContext` of the `Grid` is `CurrentMonitorAlert`. The `DataContext` of the `StackPanel` is `MonitorAlertViewModel`. Thus, the binding to `NoMonitorsMessageVisibility` is resolving against the wrong thing in your `Grid` case.

Setting the `DataContext` like that all over your view is somewhat unorthodox. Normally when doing MVVM you let WPF handle setting the `DataContext` (except possibly at the root level) and use deeper paths in your bindings if necessary. You might want to consider taking that approach.